# How to stop a Tkinter.Listbox from resizing when adding new text inside of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

So, I am trying to set a Listbox widget that will contain a table with many rows when I import a file. I want to be able to import another file and concatenate the new data. The problem is that I'm not being able to fix the Listbox size and scroll it vertically.

When importing a second file, the listbox will increase it's height indefinitely to hold the new text rows, and then, the scrollbar is not being usable.

Some images:
[Starting the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93yJV.png) > [Importing the first file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKnni.png) > [Importing the second file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxxIB.png)

The code: (edit: listbox is almost in the end of code)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from entrada import *
from saida import *

# instanciating a window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Pozzani')
window.resizable(False, False)
window.minsize(width=500, height=500)
window.geometry("500x500")
# apply the grid layout
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

top_frame = tk.Frame()
top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

# IMPORT FRAME
import_frame = tk.Frame(master=window)
import_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)
# import text
import_text = tk.Label(master=top_frame, text="Importar Extrato")
import_text.pack()

# Lancamentos
j = 1
lancamentos = {
    'Lancamento': [],
    'Data': [],
    'Debito': [],
    'Credito': [],
    'Valor': []
}

# choose file dialog
init = True
def import_file(banco):
    try:
        entrada = eval(banco.get() + '(filedialog.askopenfilename())')
    except:
        return False
    
    global lancamentos, j
    entrada.getLancamentos(lancamentos)
    
    # show on file frame
        # lancamento title
    label_lancamento = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text='Lançamento', bg='white')
    label_lancamento.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
        # data title
    label_data = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text='Data', bg='white')
    label_data.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
        # debito title
    label_debito = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text='Débito', bg='white')
    label_debito.grid(row=0, column=2)
    
        # credito title
    label_credito = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text='Crédito', bg='white')
    label_credito.grid(row=0, column=3)
    
        # valor title
    label_valor = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text='Valor', bg='white')
    label_valor.grid(row=0, column=4)
    
    # imported values
    for i in range(1, len(entrada.lancamento)):
        # lancamento
        label_lancamento = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text=lancamentos['Lancamento'][i-1], bg='white')
        label_lancamento.grid(row=j, column=0)
        
        # data
        label_data = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text=lancamentos['Data'][i-1], bg='white')
        label_data.grid(row=j, column=1)
        
        # valor
        label_valor = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text=lancamentos['Valor'][i-1], bg='white')
        label_valor.grid(row=j, column=4)
        
        if entrada.isConfigured(i-1, lancamentos):
            # debito
            debito = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text=lancamentos['Debito'][i-1], bg='white')
            debito.grid(row=j, column=2)

            # credito
            credito = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text=lancamentos['Credito'][i-1], bg='white')
            credito.grid(row=j, column=3)
            
        else:
            # importar do plano de contas . xlsx
            contas = [10, 700, 800, 900]
            
            # debito
            debito = tk.IntVar(file_frame)
            # debito.set(1)
            debito_list = tk.OptionMenu(file_frame, debito, *contas)
            debito_list.grid(row=j, column=2)

            # credito
            credito = tk.IntVar(file_frame)
            # credito.set(1)
            credito_list = tk.OptionMenu(file_frame, credito, *contas)
            credito_list.grid(row=j, column=3)
            
            config_button = tk.Button(master=file_frame, text='Add', command = lambda temp=[lancamentos['Lancamento'][i-1], debito, credito, i-1, entrada, debito_list, credito_list] : addButton(temp))
            config_button.grid(row=j, column=5)
            
        j += 1
    
    # export button
    global init
    if init:
        export_button = tk.Button(master=export_frame, text='Exportar Lançamentos', command = lambda temp=entrada : export_file(temp))
        export_button.pack()
        init = False
    else:
        pass
    
def addButton(temp):
    lancamento, debito, credito, i, entrada, debito_list, credito_list = temp
    entrada.configure(lancamento, debito, credito, i)
    global lancamentos
    
    debito_list.grid_forget()
    debito = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text=lancamentos['Debito'][i])
    debito.grid(row=i+1, column=2)
    credito_list.grid_forget()
    credito = tk.Label(master=file_frame, text=lancamentos['Credito'][i])
    credito.grid(row=i+1, column=3)
        
def export_file(entrada):
    saida = Saida()
    for i in range(len(lancamentos['Lancamento'])):
        saida.addLancamento(lancamentos['Lancamento'][i], lancamentos['Data'][i], lancamentos['Debito'][i], lancamentos['Credito'][i], lancamentos['Valor'][i])
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx")
    saida.writeLancamentos(file)
    tk.messagebox.showinfo("Success.",  f'Exportado para: \n{file}')
    
# bank chooser box
banks = ['Itau']

bank_label = tk.Label(master=import_frame, text='Banco:')
bank_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
bank = tk.StringVar(import_frame)
bank_list = tk.OptionMenu(import_frame, bank, *banks)
bank_list.grid(row=0, column=1)
            
# import file button
import_button = tk.Button(master=import_frame, text='Escolher arquivo', command = lambda temp=bank : import_file(temp))
import_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

# FILE FRAME
file_frame = tk.Listbox(window, height=20, width=500)
file_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(window,orient='vertical',command=file_frame.yview)
scroll.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nse") # set this to column=2 so it sits in the correct spot.
file_frame.yview = scroll.set

# export frame
export_frame = tk.Frame(master=window, width=500, height=100)
export_frame.grid(row=3, column=0)


# loop window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `file_frame.insert('end', ...)` to insert text into the listbox instead of packing labels into the listbox?

Comment: For your case, using `Treeview` instead of `Listbox` is better option.

Comment: You cannot scroll labels added to a listbox.

Comment: @acw1668 I don't know how that works, and I'm packing as grid, is it possible to do that with that insert('end', ...) method?

Comment: @BryanOakley what would be the better choice in this case?

Comment: That depends on the data. You can use a treeview, you could use multiple synchronized listboxes, a canvas, or a text widget. Those are all scrollable and can be used to show text.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've changed from listbox to treeview and the problem remains the same. The scrollbar is there but the treeview widget just keep growing with each new label inserted, going through the window

Comment: You can't add labels to the treeview. It has methods for adding columns of data.